# How can I dynamically generate robots.txt correctly?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have several sites, all of them have the same robots.txt.

When I modify one I have to modify others. That so troubles some.

I have an idea that generated robots.txt by back-end code. The back-end will get the data from a remote server by WEB API and generate it.

Here is the code from a tutorial in StackOverflow:

```
public class OthersController: Controller
    {
    [Route("/robots.txt")]                
    public ContentResult RotbotsTXT()
    {
        String Result=///some code get robots data from remote server.
        return this.Content(Result, "text/plain", Encoding.UTF8);
    }
}
```

In spite, it works well on the browser.

However, I met a strange situation.

Some spiders access the route correctly but can not detect it(for example Baidu spider).

And also, some spiders(for example Google bot) will strangely access route [www.abc.com//robots.txt](http://www.abc.com//robots.txt) (the robots.txt never store in here) but not [www.abc.com/robots.txt](http://www.abc.com/robots.txt).

After return to the old way by creating a TXT file, all problems are clear.

What's wrong with my code? How can I solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change `[Route("/robots.txt")]` to `[Route("robots.txt")]` like this:

```
public class OthersController: Controller
    {
    [Route("robots.txt")]                
    public ContentResult RobotsTXT()
    {
        String Result=///some code get robots data from remote server.
        return this.Content(Result, "text/plain", Encoding.UTF8);
    }
}
```

Comment: Emmm... it seems can solve the problem of Google bot access.  However, some spiders seem still can not detect it(I test it with this:http://stool.chinaz.com/robots).

Comment: Does it work when you try to go to it in your browser?

Comment: No matter whether I change the route, it works well on the browser.

Comment: I test the route with www.abc.com/robots.txt.

Comment: Test your own robots.txt, not ABC news' robots.txt.